# Simple formatting of output in columns

Tags: perl

I'm new in Perl. I wrote some code which prints output to a file in rows. I want it to be formatted in columns. Each column would have my name with number as the column heading. Please have a look at my code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $i=0;
open(OUTPUT,">Test.txt");
while ($i<=3){
printf (OUTPUT "#----------------------- \n");
printf (OUTPUT "Chironjeet Chaki No.[$i]\n");
printf (OUTPUT "#-----------------------\n");
$i++;
}
close(OUTPUT);
```

I would for suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Exactly how is this not working for you? And why are you opening the file TWICE?

Comment: What's your expected output? Also: `strict` and `warnings` are good things to put in your code.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific output, you can print each line at the same time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $OUT, '>', 'Test.txt' or die $!;

print {$OUT} '#----------------------- ' x 3, "\n";

print {$OUT} "Chironjeet Chaki No.[$_]  " for 1 .. 3;
print {$OUT} "\n";

print {$OUT} '#----------------------- ' x 3, "\n";

close $OUT;
```

In more complicated cases, you'd have to remember the contents of some of the lines and print them once they're finished.